# WP Elementor Free: How do I get a button to execute a script?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick, elementor, buttonclick

I have Zoho SalesIQ on my WordPress website designed with Elementor Free. It shows as a floating sticky widget and lets visitors chat with me. I want to insert a non-floating button on the page (in various spots) that lets visitors initiate a chat on click.

Zoho Support says this is possible, and provided the following instructions:

> You need to create a custom button and then you have to invoke the API which is provided below in it.
>
> Invoke the following code during the "on click" event/action of the custom button on your website
>
> $zoho.salesiq.floatwindow.visible('show');
>
> Sample:  Live Chat

I inserted this code in an HTML widget in Elementor Free, but I cannot insert this code in a button widget.

**How do I insert this code in an Elementor Free button widget to invoke the API and initiate a chat when the button is clicked?**

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm not a professional coder. I believe the code is JavaScript, but I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've sort of solved this problem. I inserted a shortcode widget where the button needs to be, and the code in the widget as below:

CHAT WITH US

It works but it's a stopgap. The button itself will now have to be customised in html rather than CSS I think.

Comment: The answer is unclear, because you are not able to include HTML code in _shortcode_ widget.